# Automatic rename filname not working fine after delete a file from list

Tags: c#, .net, file-rename

I am saving file names in database. Before saving I am checking to see if the filename exists in the database already. If it does, I want to append a unique ID after the file name, for example (1) or (2) and so on after the file name.

Everything is working fine, but when I delete a file from the retrieved list and from the database, sometimes a get a duplicate file name. My code is:

```
var count = dbitems().Count(x.Name == name || x.Name.Contains(name + "("));         
if (count > 0)
{
    name = name + string.Format("({0})", count);
}
```

Suppose I have saved 4 files with names

```
(1) File   
(2) File(1)    
(3) File(2)    
(4) File(3)
```

And from this list I have deleted File(2). When I try to save a file with the name "File" my output is File(3), but this already exists. The required output should be "File(2)" (as (2) was deleted and this name can be allocated) or "File(4)". I have tried with count + 1 also but this is also creating problem.

In simple words, I want behavior like windows explorer to create new name that automatically assigns a unique suffix.

Comment: Use a debugger, set breakpoints, observe what happens in the critical cases...

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it in a loop:

```
string origName = name;
int version = 0;
while(dbitems().Count(x.Name == name) > 0)         
{
    name = origName  + string.Format("({0})", ++version);
}
```

This tries name, name(1), name(2), ... until it finds a free "slot". It will also work if

name, name(1), name(5), name(6)

already exist

Comment: You'll want to start version with 1 to match the OP's question

Comment: just changed to `++version` to make it start with (1)

Comment: It would be faster to do an `Any()` rather than force a `Count()` as the iterator can return as soon as it has found a candidate, rather than running through the whole enumeration (be that a database table or otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys for your kind help. I appreciate all of you. Here is what i implement as my solution.

```
      public string UniqueName(string name, int parentId)
        {
           var files = allFiles.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId).ToList();               

            var newName = name;
            if (files.Count() > 0)
            {
                for (var i = 1; i <= matches; i++)
                {
                    if (files.Any(x => x.Name == newName 
                        newName = string.Format("{0}({1})", name, i);

                    else
                        return newName 

                }

            }

            return newName 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You're going to need to check each candidate name, so maybe something more like:

```
int count = 0;
string baseName = name;
while (dbitems().Any(x.Name == name))
{
    count++;
    name = string.Format("{1} ({0})", count, baseName);
}
```

Comment: @Schuere No, if name does not exist in DB there is no "first time"

Comment: @DrKoch there wasn't a basename variable untill now, the answer is correct and as such i will remove my -1 EDIT, doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Schuere Yes, I know, Rowland edited his answer towards a better answer

Comment: so I commented on the incomplete answer which was wrong and now it is complete so I can remove my previous comment and add +1 :)